# Is it possible to create a second-generation Managed Package with a ConnectedApp without a first-generation Managed Package?

Tags: managed-package, connected-apps, second-generation-packaging

Looking at [Salesforce's documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_connected_app.htm), it appears the only way to create a **ConnectedApp** in a second-generation **Managed Package** is to first create it in a first-generation **Managed Package**?

Is this true even if I'm creating the second-generation **Managed Package** from scratch?

**UPDATE**: This appears to be true as ConnectedApps are "fundamentally tied to 1GP infrastructure". :-(

**Follow up to Phil W's question, "Do you really need a ConnectedApp?"**
**Answer**: I'm not sure but open to alternatives. Our Managed Package (among other things) enables us to use the **OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Flow for Server-to-Server Integration** to connect to each org where our Managed Package is installed to get updates to Opportunities via the Salesforce REST API. The ConnectedApp has our certificate associated. We use the Consumer Key, Secret and the private key for our certificate to make a secure connection. Aside from Apex REST, is there an alternative that would allow us to use the Salesforce REST API to retrieve info from each org?

Comment: Is there a reason to actually try to package your connected app? Do you need a new ID and secret for every install, or could you use a common connected app for every install of your package? The latter is my recommendation if at all possible. According to a conversation I had with Salesforce PM for packaging Connected Apps are fundamentally tied to 1GP infrastructure.

Comment: Hi Phil W - good question. I added some detail above in response. Curious about your thoughts.

Comment: I'll ping some of the Salesforce gurus to see what they think and hopefully get their answer here.

Comment: Thanks - really appreciate the help!